# How to replace special characters to underscore(_) perl

Tags: regex, linux, perl

```
my @folder = ('s,c%','c__pp_p','Monday_øå_Tuesday,  Wednesday','Monday &       Tuesday','Monday_Tuesday___Wednesday');

if ($folder =~ s/[^\w_*\-]/_/g ) {
  $folder =~ s/_+/_/g;
  print "$folder : Got %\n" ; 
}
```

Using above code i am not able to handle this "Monday_øå_Tuesday_Wednesday"

The output should be :

```
s_c
c_pp_p
Monday_øå_Tuesday_Wednesday
Monday_Tuesday
Monday_Tuesday_Wednesday
```

Comment: **\w** only matches  a "word" character (alphanumeric plus "_", plus other connector punctuation chars plus Unicode marks) see: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\W` to negate the `\w` character class, but the problem you've got is that `\w` doesn't match your non-ascii letters.

So you need to do something like this instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @folder = ('s,c%','c__pp_p','Monday_øå_Tuesday,  Wednesday','Monday &       Tuesday','Monday_Tuesday___Wednesday');

s/[^\p{Alpha}]+/_/g for @folder;
print Dumper \@folder;
```

Outputs:

```
$VAR1 = [
          's_c_',
          'c_pp_p',
          'Monday_øå_Tuesday_Wednesday',
          'Monday_Tuesday',
          'Monday_Tuesday_Wednesday'
        ];
```

This uses a unicode property - these are documented in [`perldoc perluniprop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops.html#Properties-accessible-through-%5Cp%7B%7D-and-%5CP%7B%7D) - but the long and short of it is, `\p{Alpha}` is the *unicode* alphanumeric set, so much like `\w` but internationalised.

Although, it does have a trailing `_` on the first line. From your description, that seems to be what you wanted. If not, then... it's probably easier to:

```
s/_$// for @folder;
```

than make a more complicated pattern.

Comment: Whats \p do ? And why is alpha in curly braces ? Nevermind, for anyone else who cares it is for unicode property.

Comment: `\p` is a unicode property. There's a load of them, and it's listed in: http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops.html#Properties-accessible-through-%5cp%7b%7d-and-%5cP%7b%7d

Comment: Yeah , found it right after asking, cheers for the reply though.